# How to get SpatiaLite to work with Cordova/Ionic Framework

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, spatialite

A am building a hybrid mobile app using the Ionic Framework and I was able to successful get SQLite to work using [ngCordova SQLite plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/):

Now I need to know how to get SpatiaLite DBMS library to work in this Ionic application.

Does anyone know how I can get SpatiaLite to work in Ionic?

Answer (score -1):

you might can use plugins which can provide spatial functionality with basic SQL storage.

Reference:-
http://blog.disy.net/spatialite-phonegap-on-mobile/
https://github.com/DisyInformationssysteme/Cordova-spatialite-storage

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12495326)

Comment: Actually i am very much new in this technology(learning). I am also trying to do the same and meanwhile I found this solution, but i don't know how to use this plugin.  also found the blog for the same but there is only one example given which is for retrieve spatial data from the table.